# Convert a two colored tree into a bipartite tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, bipartite

Given a two colored tree (say red and blue), I want to convert it into a bipartite tree by swapping colors of adjacent nodes.
Also I want to keep the number of swaps minimal. I am not able to approach the minimal swaps part.
Although I have written a dfs code that assumes root to be say red and counts the number of required red and blue nodes. If we have sufficient colors to make the tree bipartite, how do we count the minimal swaps?

```
void dfs(vector<vector<ll>> &adj , ll node , ll parent , ll val)
{
    if(val == 0) red++;
    else 
    {
        blue++;
    }

    for(auto x : adj[node])
    {
        if(x!=parent)
            dfs(adj ,  x , node , val^1 );
    }
       return;
}

if(givenred == red || givenred == blue)
       // count minimal swaps
else
       // not possible
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you've decided which nodes need to be which color, then:

1. Pick a root, if you don't already have one
2. For each subtree, calculate how many red nodes *should* be in that subtree
3. For each subtree, calculate how many red nodes *are* in that subtree
4. Add up that magnitudes of the difference for every subtree.

For each subtree, the magnitude of the difference is the number of swaps that have to happen across the edge to its parent.

The algorithm takes linear time, since each step can be done in linear time with DFS.  You can try both color assignments (root red or root blue) and pick the smaller total.